# onMenuItemActionCollapse not called in orientation change

Tags: android

I am using ABS Search widget for my search operation, and I am facing a problem that onMenuItemActionCollapse is not being called on orientation change when clicking done button of search widget. I provide the my code below which I am currently using...

```
item.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {

                @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("collapse", "Expand Called");
                                    return true;
                            }
                            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.e("collapse", "collapse Called");
                                    return true;
                            }
```

On click of search item from action bar Item Expand is called and on click of done button/hard back button Item Collapse is called. But an unexpected behavior happens when item expand is called and on orientation change item collapse is not being called.

Kindly Suggest me the reason of this issue.

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

On this case， you can configure screen orientation change by set `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`,
then the activity will not be recreated, instead activity `onConfigurationChanged` will be called, in that method, you can do something for collapse since you know who are expended there.

Comment: config changes is not acceptable for activity having multiple layouts.. any other possiblity

Comment: @Venkatraman Then I suggest you use 'onSaveInstanceState', that was called before your former activity destroyed, there, you know who was expended and its  'onMenuItemActionCollapse' should be called, mark the state with flags, then in 'onDestory' you can check the flags and do the work you want to do with 'onMenuItemActionCollapse'.
Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle).
This will work but I have to say it is not a perfect answer, looking forward to some other's perfect answer.

Comment: Since I am newbie in this fragments concepts can u give me some samples

Comment: actually we can do it more simple, your class field: boolean flag_menu_a_expanded = false; in 'onMenuItemActionExpand': flag_menu_a_expanded = true, in 'onMenuItemActionCollapse' flag_menu_a_expanded = false; then in 'onDestroy', check flag_menu_a_expanded, if is true, then do the work you want to do with your 'onMenuItemActionCollapse' .